# Validation for current user

Tags: django

How to realize checking 'name' for current user in forms.py in ValidationError('Same name already added, change name').

```
views.py

@login_required
def main_page(request):
form = URL_listForm(request.POST)
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        if URL_list.objects.filter(user=request.user, name=name).exists():
            return HttpResponse('Same name already added, change name')
        new_post = form.save(commit=False)
        new_post.user = request.user
        new_post.save()
        return HttpResponse("Data added")
return render(request, 'link/main.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want validate in database

```
 #-------ADDED CODE
 data_tmp = """SELECT count(*) from jobtest WHERE link = %s""", (line)
 data_tmp = cur.fetchall()
 #-------END ADDED CODE

 if (data_tmp == 0 ) :
        Not exist
```

add form with name

```
<input type="text" id="projectName" size="40" placeholder="Spot your project files">
<input type="button" id="spotButton" value="Spot">
```

when press post button and action to api you can get value in input field  using request.form['Name']

if you want send data from server code to html

return render_template('index.html', data=userinfo)
and render as
{% userinfo %}

Comment: But i want 2 know solution, how 2 send current user to form, and get data form name field)